# Project Euler #39: Is there a more efficient way to solve this problem?

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I am doing [Integer right triangles](https://projecteuler.net/problem=39). I have written a very simple brute force solution that runs through every combination.

I am pretty sure that there would be a better method for working out the answer but I can't think of any that reduce the computational complexity. Here's my current solution:

```
const main = () => {

    let map = new Map();

    for (let a = 1; a < 1001; a++) {
        for (let b = a; b < 1001; b++) {

            const c = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(a, 2) + Math.pow(b, 2));
            const perimeter = (a + b + c);

            if (perimeter > 1000) {
                break;
            }

            if (c % 1 === 0) {
                map.set(perimeter, (map.get(perimeter) ? map.get(perimeter) + 1 : 1));
            }
        }
    }

    // Sorting by the incremented value then returning the highest
    return new Map([...map.entries()].sort((a, b) => b[1] - a[1]))
        .entries()
        .next()
        .value[0];
};

console.log(main());
```

Thanks!

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_triple#Generating_a_triple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some remarks about your code:

- As the perimeter cannot be larger than 1000, and *a < b < c*, *a* should not have to iterate up to 1000, but only to 332. Similarly, *b* should not iterate further than *1000 - 2*a*.
- You can avoid taking the square root by increasing the previous value for *c* with 1, and adjusting the corresponding square. Similarly you can apply incremental logic to the squares of a and b, and the sum of squares.
- Sorting is overkill. You only need to find the entry with the maximum count. So just iterate over the `map` to find that maximum

Before showing a faster method, the above will already speed up your code considerably. Your code would then look like this:

```js
const main = () => {
    let map = new Map();
    for (let a = 1; a < 333; a++) {
        let limit = 1000 - 2*a;
        let aSquare = Math.pow(a, 2);
        let aSquarePlusBSquare = 2*aSquare;
        let c = Math.floor(a * 1.14142);
        let cSquare = c*c;
        let perimeter = 2*a+c;
        for (let b = a+1; b < limit; b++) {
            aSquarePlusBSquare += 2*b - 1;
            perimeter++;
            while (cSquare < aSquarePlusBSquare) {
                c++;
                perimeter++;
                cSquare += 2*c - 1;
            }
            if (perimeter > 1000) {
                break;
            }
            if (cSquare === aSquarePlusBSquare) {
                map.set(perimeter, (map.get(perimeter) ? map.get(perimeter) + 1 : 1));
            }
        }
    }
    let max = 0;
    for (let [i, k] of map) {
        if (k <= max) continue;
        max = k;
        result = i;
    }
    return result;
};
console.log(main());
```

Now, you can also go for a different algorithm. I implemented one that uses the [tree of primitive Pythagorian triplets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_of_primitive_Pythagorean_triples). This performs 20 times better than your original code, and like 5 times better than the above implementation:

```js
function main() {
    let map = new Map;

    function recur(a, b, c) {
        let sum = a+b+c;
        if (sum >= 1001) return;
        // As this is a primitive case, also count the multiples:
        for (let p = sum; p < 1001; p += sum) map.set(p, map.get(p)+1 || 1);
        // Calculate the 3 "children" of this primitive Pythagorean triple, 
        //    using Berggren's tree 
        let a2 = a<<1, a4 = a<<2, b2 = b<<1, b4 = b<<2;
        let temp = a2 - b2 + (c<<1);
        a = temp - a;
        b += temp;
        c += temp;
        recur(a, b, c);
        a += b4;
        b += b2;
        c += b4;
        recur(a, b, c);
        recur(a-a2, b-a4, c-a4);
    }
    recur(3, 4, 5);
    
    let max = 0;
    for (let [i, k] of map) {
        if (k <= max) continue;
        max = k;
        result = i;
    }
    return result;
}

console.log(main());
```